# Is there a way to close Window Popup when clicking other Fragments of an Activity.?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have created Window popup in Fragment-A. I would like to get it close if user clicks other Fragment (Fragment B or Fragment C). Request you to advise how this can be achieved.

Below is my code for creating Fragment

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentA(), "FragA");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentB, "FragB");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentC, "FragC");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
```

Code for creating PoPup

```
        View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, 
    null);
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, false);
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupView, mEditText.getScrollX(), 
   mEditText.getScrollY()-50);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
   popupView.findViewById(R.id.popuprelativelayout);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        adapterString = new AdapterString(popupWindow,userfollowlist, 
   getContext(), mEditText,isWinOpen);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterString);
            isWinOpen = true;
}
```

Have tried to use below method but change in fragment is not getting sensed.

```
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    if(!hidden)
    {
        if(isWinOpen) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            isWinOpen = false;
        }
    }
      }
```

As described previously will appreciate if you can advise how Popup Window can be dismissed when other Fragments are clicked.

Thanks in advance for your help!!!!!

Comment: Please don't tag questions with IDE tags (android-studio) just because you use that IDE: these tags should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and the [tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Also, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: use `setUserVisibleHint' method for that.

Comment: setUserVisibleHint method is called before the onCreateView method so on first Fragment loaded this method will not work. My window popup is on first fragment itself. Pls suggest..